# How to retrieve AssemblyVersionAttribute in MSBuild script

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

When trying to retrieve the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.2.3.4")]` present in AssemblyInfo.cs file from a custom MSBuild script, I always get `$(Version)` value `1.0.0.0` instead of the value written in the file.

Can somebody tell me how to fix this issue? Unfortunately, other entries I have found so far, didn't point me to the right direction.

Comment: The `$(Version)` is the nuget package version rather than the assembly dll version.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually**, you just want to get the assembly dll version by **MSBuild** rather the nuget package version.

`$(Version)` is the value of the nuget package version after you pack the lib project. See [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli#set-properties).

If you want to get the internal assembly dll version, it can be a bit complex but it can be done with some MSBuild tasks.

Use this:

```
<Target Name="RetrieveIdentities" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <GetAssemblyIdentity
            AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
            <Output
                TaskParameter="Assemblies"
                ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>           
        </GetAssemblyIdentity>
        
        <Message Text="Version: %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version)"/>
            
</Target>
```

And `%(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version)` is the value of the `AssemblyVersion`.